# enqueue script only if it is not already enqueue

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, wp-enqueue-script

I want to include a script in a shortcode output, so I am trying this:

```
function my_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'title'  => '',
           ), $atts));

    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script'); 

}
```

I have registered the script already and enqueue it if the above shortcode is used.
However I want to include the file only once, even if the shortcode is used multiple times. Currently, if the shortcode is used multiple times, it will include the script for each time. Is it possible?

Comment: _will include the script for each time_ < have you tested this? I don't think enqueue even _can_ produce multiple copies of same script.

Comment: You're right. I should have tested it more before posting the question. It was problem in my code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The WordPress enqueue system should prevent the inclusion of the same script multiple times, and does when I test it. For example, the following enqueues a Core script and `echo`s a counter. If I put this shortcode into a post 4 times, I get "0123" but the media script only loads one time. The same test works with several other scripts I tried.

```
function my_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'title'  => '',
           ), $atts));
    static $counter = 0;
    echo $counter++;
    wp_enqueue_script('wp-mediaelement'); 

}
add_shortcode('enq','my_shortcode');
```

If you are getting the same script loaded over and over, there is a problem with your site, but I am not sure where start guessing at what.

Comment: +1. The underlying premise of the question is wrong, as it misunderstands what it means for WordPress to *enqueue* a script.

Comment: it is not prevent duplicate when it is hooked to custom hook.

Comment: I don't know what that means @SoursopTree

Comment: I tried it using shortcode. I created a custom action hook inside a shortcode function, then hook `wp_enqueue_style` to it! I checked it using firebug html inspector and I found duplicate stylesheet.

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong! I named the directories and files similarly, so it looks like that there are duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`wp_script_is()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is) to determine if a script is enqueued - and use it in a conditional, like this:

```
if( ! wp_script_is( 'custom-script', 'enqueued' ) ) {
    // your code here
}
```

[`wp_script_is()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is) takes *two parameters* - `$handle` and `$list` - the latter can be: `registered`, `enqueued`/`queue`, `done` or `to_do`; and it returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: While that may not be incorrect, wp_enqueue_script already checks for you, so this code is completely redundant.

Comment: You're right about that, nothing more to say, so I generalized the answer. @JakeParis